# Script for Editing TIN in Arcgis: modelbuilder works, when exported as script gives an error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, 3d-analyst, tin, error-000800

Arcgis can give such a headache!
I want to automate loads of small tasks, and so I need to edit empty TIN with python in order to create a full TIN.
My srcript is giving errors, so I tried by hand to make it work with ModelBuilder AND EditTIN IT WORKS FINE!!!!

Exported the same Model (that just worked) as python script gives errors!

```
# Local variables...
raster = "F:\\...\\mClip_1"
raster_InterpolateShape = "F:\\...\\mClip_1_InterpolateShape"
# Process: Edit TIN...
gp.EditTin_3d(raster, "raster_InterpolateShape Shape <None> softline true")
```

and the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\....\test_editTin.py", line 26, in <module>
    gp.EditTin_3d(raster, "raster_InterpolateShape Shape <None> softline true")
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of <None>.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of %s.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of %s.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of %s.
Failed to execute (EditTin).
```

All extensions and everything is checked since it is exported from model builder.
I suppose something wrong is just with first shp input

In ArcgisHelp ex for the input 3d shp name it shows the name with extension

```
..."masspntz.shp Shape <None> masspoints true"
```

And so I tried both, with extension and without, but the same errors come.

Any ideas, how can I get that TIN from feature automatically.. ???

Comment: Post your script if you can.

Comment: The script or process of the script is clear from the error message, as the rest is just variable definition, tool adding and so on... Well, can post variable if that would change smth :/

Comment: If you can give us the full script it will help with debugging. It is probably a small syntax error, but without the full code its hard to say what it is.

Comment: indeed it's just syntax. I've found that Arcgis requires here in a script a FULL PATH, so the problem can be solved simply adding variable and joining with the rest to be string.. : gp.EditTin_3d(raster, raster_InterpolateShape+" Shape <None> softline true")

Answer (score 2):

Problem of the exporting was that I used local variables.. (Drag and drop from the same environment).
And the problem of my script was that following the ArcgisHELP I also used local variables..

For scripting, when EDIT TIN, the full path with data source must be added, 
so insted just using variable, or local parameters:

```
gp.EditTin_3d(raster, "raster_InterpolateShape Shape <None> softline true")
```

should go (variable plus string and then also sapce is important):

```
gp.EditTin_3d(raster, raster_InterpolateShape+" Shape <None> softline true")
```

Hr... so simple..

Comment: Hi @najuste, I ran into similar problem. I tried below combinations. But none of them worked for me. `arcpy.CreateTin_3d(shift_dx, "", shift_tin_source+" dx masspoints", "DELAUNAY")`, `arcpy.CreateTin_3d(shift_dx, None, shift_tin_source+" dx masspoints None", "DELAUNAY")` and `arcpy.CreateTin_3d(shift_dx, None, shift_tin_source+" dx masspoints None", "DELAUNAY")`. Thought to share with you. Perhaps you can throw some more light on this.